# C#: Import FDF/XML data via IAcroAXDocShim for a PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, adobe, fdf

I'm trying to import form data for a PDF after the PDF has loaded. I'm using a WPF `WebBrowser` control to display the PDF and use the Navigate method to open my PDF. This works and I can keep calling Navigate to open my PDF when I want to update the view. As an improvement however, I'd like to just reload the form data every time and not the entire Adobe control. Using the Document from the `WebBrowser`, I can get an instance of an `IAcroAXDocShim`, but there's no documentation of how I can call to import the form data again. Does anyone have any suggestions for me? If I open the PDF in Adobe directly, I can choose Document -> Forms -> Import Data. This is the command I want to call programmatically. Thanks in advance for any help!